# Magento2. Работа с фильтрами

Tags: php

Читаю документацию по magento2, наткнулся на данную картинку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка документации: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/pattern-library/displaying-data/datatable/datatable.html

И заметил, что фильтры стоят в самих колонках, а не по кнопку filters. Как мне реализовать такое ? Нигде не смогу найти код, который нужно использовать.

Код моего XML файла filters:

```
 <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
```

Код колонки:

```
<column name="title">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="width" xsi:type="string">150px</item>
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                 <item name="headerTmpl" xsi:type="string" >ui/grid/columns/donordrives</item>
                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                 <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                 <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                 <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                 <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">title</item>
             </item>
         </argument>
     </column>
```

На данный момент мои фильтры вот такие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]